# My SQL combine join queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks for taking time to read this.

I am currently stuck on how to make these 2 separate query work together, both work as i want them to individually, please note the syntax is according to a application i use that uses mysql to manipulate columns in an imported csv file.

this one.

adds at and replaces homebuy url

```
CONCAT('at-', 


        REPLACE([CSV_COL(18)],'http://www.homebuy.co.uk/product.php/','')

      )
```

---

removes last character  i.e.   /

```
SUBSTRING([CSV_COL(18)], 1, CHAR_LENGTH([CSV_COL(18)]) - 1)
```

basically i need these 2 to work together to give me an output like this

at-09fd8903

from the this

http://www.homebuy.co.uk/product.php/09fd8903/

as i said both work on there own, but not together.

So any ideas would be truly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted.

```
concat('at-', 
    SUBSTRING(
           REPLACE([CSV_COL(18)],'http://www.homebuy.co.uk/product.php/',''),
    1, CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE([CSV_COL(18)],'http://www.homebuy.co.uk/product.php/','')) - 1) 
)
```

You can use other functions within functions, just like most other languages.

Comment: i get only at  doing this not what i want at-09fd8903

Comment: try the above.  I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply  by doing this is still adding the / at the end which im trying to remove   at-09fd8903/   how do i get rid of the /   please  so its like this at-09fd8903

Comment: try increasing the - 1 to - 2

Comment: i did try that already and -3 but it doesnt remove anything at moment its just doing the first part of adding at and removing url  but last part its not doing.

Comment: logic problem, we were looking at the length of the original query.  You could change it as above or change the -1 to -37 (or maybe 38, I can't recall offhand how MySQL counts substring).  If the second part is the same length every time you can modify the substring to be substring (big replace statement), 1, (whatever the length of the first part is)

Comment: thanks the url is not fixed length otherwise it would make things easier, if we increase to 38 its then removing all the charachters we want to keep aswell. can a TRIM last not work just to get rid of the last charachter, i checked few tutorials but i dont know how to combine TRIM with this mysql as i get syntax error

Comment: yeah you can replace the substring bit with trim(TRAILING '/' from REPLACE([CSV_COL(18)],'http://www.homebuy.co.uk/product.php/','') )